# version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference

Tags: package-management, python, software-center

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. 
When I import pyrosetta from python terminal by typing

***>>> import pyrosetta; pyrosetta.init()***

It shows an error massage as shown below:

***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrosetta-2018.02_release.d2f80a3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyrosetta/__init__.py", line 15, in 
    import pyrosetta.rosetta as rosetta
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrosetta-2018.02_release.d2f80a3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyrosetta/rosetta.so: symbol _ZTINSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference***

I have gcc version 4.8.5.

Can anyone please tell me what is the meaning of this error & how to solve it?

Comment: It seemed that you installed pyrosetta manually, and that the version you installed is not compatible with Ubuntu 14.04. You need to find a compatible version.

Comment: I installed the lower version, pyrosetta3. still it shows the same error.